# Validate Time of user input

Tags: javascript, time, readline

I need to write a function to validate the time of user input from console. The format of the time is HH:mm in 24 hours time.

```
function isValidTime(timeString) {
    var regex_time = /^\d{2}\:\d{2}$/;

    if(!regex_time.test(timeString))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var hour = timeString.getHour();
    var minute = timeString.getMinutes();

    if ((hour > 0 && hour <= 23) && (minute > 0 && minute <= 59)) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the code I have so far. When I input 5:01, the output is invalid format. When I input 17:01, it shows

```
node:internal/readline/emitKeypressEvents:71
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: timeString.getHour is not a function
```

Could you please help with this function, I am reading user input with readline.

Comment: You're trying to call Date methods (`.getHour` and `.getMinutes`) on a string.  That won't work.  Use capture groups in your regex instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use capture groups in the regular expression... And the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

Match will return `null` if no match at all
or an array containing the full match at position 0 followed by all capture group results.

```js
function isValidTime(timeString) {
    const regex_time = /^(\d{2})\:(\d{2})$/;  // Use capture groups

    const timeMatches = timeString.match(regex_time)
    if(!timeMatches){
      return false
    }
    const hour = parseInt(timeMatches[1])
    const minute = parseInt(timeMatches[2])

    return hour >= 0 && hour <= 23 && minute >= 0 && minute <= 59
}

console.log(isValidTime("5:01"))  // false

console.log(isValidTime("17:05"))  // true
```

Comment: Look at my edit... Improved the function returned using the condition directly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>       
        <input type="text" placeholder="MM" id="month">
        <input type="text" placeholder="DD" id="date">
        <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY" id="year">
        <button>Check</button>
        <h1>Result</h1>    
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>





let btnCheck = document.querySelector('button');
let inputMonth = document.querySelector('#month');
let inputDate = document.querySelector('#date');
let inputYear = document.querySelector('#year');
let result = document.querySelector('h1');


btnCheck.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let month = inputMonth.value;
    let year = inputYear.value;
    let date = inputDate.value;

    // true in the end, so that our date string and date format should match exactly - in moment js it is called Strict Parsing
    result.innerText = moment(`${month}/${date}/${year}`, 'MM/DD/YYYY', true).isValid();
});
```

Comment: hope this will work :)

Comment: Thank you, I know moment.js but I am not allowed to use it

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.

Comment: ans are useful run on editor

Answer (score -2):

Solution :

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var hour = today.getHours (
var minutes = today.getMinutes
```

Another Tip :

If you Get A Another Error you can write

```
var today = new Date();
var parag = document.getElementById("date")
var time = today.getHours () + ":" + today.getMinutes () + ":" + today.getSeconds();
parag.innerHTML = time
```

Comment: Answers on Stackoverflow have to be self-contained. Don't post links to your answer.

Comment: How i will Show to user code?

Comment: About question/answer [formatting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), here is a useful page to bookmark ;)

Comment: How could posting a screenshot of code be a good idea?

Comment: Lilla, to be a good contributor to Stack Overflow, you'll need to learn how to properly format your answers.  I've OCR'd your images and edited the code into your answer. Please take a little more time in the future to format your answers with the SO markup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).